# ASP.NET MVC URL routing doesn't give me pretty URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have set up an ASP.NET MVC project, and everything is working great, but I do have one problem with the routing. My Global.asax looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

So, nothing out of the ordinary. My problem is that when I link to a controller/action/params with an HTML.ActionLink like so:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("My link", "SomeAction", "SomeController", new {param="someParam"})%>
```

it should generate (at least what makes sense in my head) a link such as: `http://www.localhost/SomeController/SomeAction/someParam`.

But instead it generates a link like this: `http://localhost/SomeController/SomeAction?param=someParam`

If i manually make a link that links to the expected result (SomeController/SomeAction/someParam) then the right controller and action are called, but the parameter defined in the action method is always null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that link will only use the default route like you expect if the parameter name is `id` instead of `param`.  You'll have to create a different route if you want to provide some other parameter there.

Comment: Hmmm, so this means that I have to specify a new routing rule for each new controller action that requires a different set of parameters? This would result a large amount of routing rules for an enterprise application. Isn't there a more dynamic approach than that?

Comment: If this was really dynamic, wouldn't you lose type safety, parameter safety and testability?

Answer (score 5):

try adding:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Default",                                                                                              // Route name
                    "{controller}/{action}/{param}",                                                   // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", param = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```